# MSSQL How to write a function , what substract data from table coloumn

Tags: sql-server, function

I'am writing a Library program.In program, the Librarian can lend books to users.
I have a "Book table" 
BookName,Title,..., ammount.

I want to write a function,on calling the function substract 1 from ammount, and update the table with ammount-1.
How can i do that?
i am rying this, but not good :(

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Lend 
(
     @katal_szam int
)
RETURNS int 
AS
BEGIN
  declare @all int, @lend int;
    Select @all = all_ammount-1, @lend=lended_ammount+1 from Konyv where katal_szam=@katal_szam

    Update Konyv
    set all_ammount=@all
    set lended_ammount=@lend
    Where katal_szam=@katal_szam

END
GO
```

Comment: _How can i do that?_ A good start might be to read the manual, or look at a tutorial. If and when you get stuck feel free to ask on specific problem you're facing.

Comment: Check my function above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions can not have statements with side-effects that change the table (like `update`), but you can write a stored procedure that does what you want. Note that a lot of the code in your function is redundant and the procedure could be shortened to:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.Lend (@katal_szam int)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Konyv
    SET all_ammount -= 1, lended_ammount += 1
    WHERE katal_szam = @katal_szam
END
```

And execute it like this:

```
exec dbo.lend 1
```

or

```
exec dbo.lend @katal_szam = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, this is excelent :R